# Does garlic prevent the spread of colds?

Tags: alternative-medicine, natural-remedies

I just heard that a friend plans to feed their toddler raw garlic because the toddler has a cold and they don't want it spreading to their infant.  Is there evidence for or against the efficacy of this practice?

Comment: If nothing else, if you smell of garlic, you may not be allowed close enough to other people to pass or get the virus! :)

Comment: Raw garlic stings... would definitely not feed it to a toddler. I could barely handle it when I took a bite and I don't think I'm a toddler...

Answer (score 2):

> there is insufficient clinical trial evidence regarding the effects
>   of garlic in preventing or treating the common cold. A single trial
>   suggested that garlic may prevent occurrences of the common cold but
>   more studies are needed to validate this finding. Claims of
>   effectiveness appear to rely largely on poor-quality evidence.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garlic#cite_ref-46) Unfortunately, I cannot access the article referred to.

Also pay attention to this:

> **Children:** Garlic is POSSIBLY SAFE when taken by mouth and appropriately for a short-term in children. But garlic is POSSIBLY UNSAFE when taken by mouth in large doses. Some sources suggest that high doses of garlic could be dangerous or even fatal to children; however, the reason for this warning is not known. There are no case reports available of significant adverse events or mortality in children associated with taking garlic by mouth.

Found at [Medline](http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/druginfo/natural/300.html)